# Does Javascript run after logout in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am beginning to think that Javascript is a useless tool to control issue with browser displaying visited pages from cached data when session has been destroyed below is my latest attempt. I used localStorage.setItem() I don't think I incorporated the code correctly. I do not know how to mesh it with WordPress "twenty sixteen" theme. Not surprisingly the code below does not work

```
<script>
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store 
    localStorage.setItem("user_login");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("user_pass").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("user_pass");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("user_pass").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to force the browser to realize that the user is logged out. If nothing is done then the browser will continue to use cached data as proof that user is logged in when in fact session has been destroyed. Again, I am trying to force the browser to realize that the user is logged out

Comment: What cached data are we talking about - this certainly isnt normal.

Comment: the cached data that indicates that the user is logged on when he/she  is not logged on. In other words the browser stores the user name and password allowing the user to see the cached pages that they visited by using the back button on the browser.